# ¿Contraindicaciones de static import?

Tags: java, constantes, java-import

Estoy analizando un código y me he encontrado la clase `Constantes`, que, tal y como su nombre indica tiene esta estructura:

```
public final class Constantes {
    public static final String PREFIJO = "prefijo_";
}
```

En otra clase he visto este `import`:

```
import static mi.paquete.Constantes.*;
```

Por lo que, al usar los atributos de la clase constantes lo hace directamente por su nombre,

```
String nombreFichero = PREFIJO + nombre;
```

Sin necesidad de referenciar la clase como con los imports normales:

```
String nombreFichero = Constantes.PREFIJO + nombre;
```

No conocía la técnica de los `import static` y me parece bastante interesante para limpiar código, siempre y cuando:

- Tu aplicación esté bien estructurada
- Se use con cabeza
- No cree confusión por saber desde dónde vienen las constantes.

Pero:

- ¿Hay alguna contraindicación a la hora de usar esta técnica?

Comment: `import static` es un feature de java, una mera dulzura sintáctica. nada de contra-indicaciones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta característica está disponible desde Java 6 y apoya bastante a la reducción y legibilidad de código. Solo ten cuidado en caso que importes de manera estática dos o más clases que posesn elementos estáticos (campo o método) con el mismo nombre puesto que el compilador no sabrá de cuál clase escoger y lanzaría un error de compilación. Aquí un ejemplo:

```
package edu.ltmj.clases;
public class Prueba {
    public static final int X = 10;
}
```

```
package edu.ltmj.interfaces;
public interface Demo {
    int X = 20;
}
```

```
package  edu.ltmj.main;
import static edu.ltmj.clases.Prueba.X;
import static edu.ltmj.interfaces.Demo.X;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int x = X; //error de compilación 
    }
}
```

Para estos casos, se resuelve utilizando la clase y nombre del campo a utilizar. Para el caso de arriba, una posible solución es:

```
//se agrega el import de la clase a utilizar
import edu.ltmj.interfaces.Demo;

//se llama al campo relevante 
int x = Demo.X;
```

Otro punto muy importante es al momento de mostrar snippets o fragmentos de código a tus compañeros o en línea donde utilizas campos estáticos, asegúrate de agregar los `import static` necesarios, sobretodo al mostrar código de librerías que no sean tan conocidas o para la documentación de cómo utilizar una librería que has creado.

Answer (score 1):

Que yo sepa no existe contraindicación ninguna, pienso que es una clara mejoria para la lectura del codigo, por ejemplo con la librería Guava, uso de *Preconditions*:

```
Preconditions.checkArgument(valor!=null);
```

contra

```
checkArgument(valor!=null);
```

Creo que es mucho mas legible.